# What we cover with iterative Fast Gradient Sign Method (iterative-FGSM) that we can't cover with simple Fast Gradient Sign Method (FGSM)

Tags: machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network, adversarial-machines

FGSM and iterative-FGSM are two methods of generating adversarial samples. After visiting hundreds of sites and blogs to know that **why in iterative-FGSM we perform multiple steps. And what we cover with multiple steps in (iterative-FGSM) that we can't cover in simple FGSM**.

But all gives me this unsatisfied answer that in iterative-FGSM we perform FGSM multiple time.
Please can anyone gives me satisfied answer to above bold question.
Thanks

Comment: @IanGoodfellow May I have your wisdom.?

Comment: As I understand, iterative-FGSM or I-FGSM will recalculate the gradient at each time-step. This is not the same as performing FGSM multiple times since we are changing the gradient. By recalculating the gradient it will be able to find a local optima with less perturbation.